# zoo - Round coredata to integer

Tags: r, rounding, lapply, zoo

I've got a list of 69 `zoo` objects, I used `na.approx` to fill few gaps, but since my time series deal with counts I need the imputed values to be integers.

This code

```
list_int <- lapply(list_dec, round(coredata(list_dec), digits=0))
```

gives me the following error message

```
Error in round(coredata(list_dec), digits=0) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I thought it was a problem with applying the function to a list instead of a vector, but the function

```
coredata(list_dec)
```

correctly shows all 69 time series (without need for `lapply`).

So why can't `round` apply to `coredata`?

**EDITED**

As suggested here's a minimal data set

```
 A1 <- runif(20, min=-5, max=13)
 A2 <- runif(20, min=-1, max=5)
 A3 <- runif(20, min=-3, max=10)
 A4 <- runif(20, min=0, max=2)
 ls <- list(A1, A2, A3, A4)
 list_dec <- lapply(ls, as.zoo)
```

Comment: Are you sure you deal with numbers and not strings that look like numbers?

Comment: Yes, before using `na.approx` they were integers, but the function coerced them to numeric

Comment: Could you post a minimal example of your dataset?

Comment: Done it. Hope it can help. The time series here are all made of real numbers, my original data set has just few reals, with most of the numbers being integers (so, they're numeric time series). Thank you

Comment: If I run lapply(list_dec,round) for the example in your edit, it works perfectly fine. Do you get the same error for this minimal example?

Comment: I didn't actually, and it works fine for me too. It works also on my original data set. Looks like `lapply` is smarter than I thought, I was providing too many arguments! Thank you! Maybe you can post it as an answer

Comment: Glad your problem is solved! As you suggested, I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can accomplish what you want by the following:

```
> library(zoo)
> A1 <- runif(20, min=-5, max=13)
> A2 <- runif(20, min=-1, max=5)
> A3 <- runif(20, min=-3, max=10)
> A4 <- runif(20, min=0, max=2)
> ls <- list(A1, A2, A3, A4)
> list_dec <- lapply(ls, as.zoo)
```

Now list_dec looks as follows:

```
> list_dec
[[1]]
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12          13 
 9.20889929  8.03050882  1.52621137  9.91528049 12.71637959 11.93573340  3.34967427  9.75224030  7.90654714  0.08199464 -2.84403691 11.57990103  4.74868873 
         14          15          16          17          18          19          20 
 2.94023319 10.71812525 -2.05394366 -1.07669056  7.17503613  4.84871327  4.58929978 

[[2]]
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13         14         15 
 1.0756646  0.5615212  0.5697795  0.9629726  2.5962021  3.1932062  0.6894849  1.9844943  1.3351256  4.0043998  0.4756172  0.4573920  0.6009208  4.4963877  4.4149804 
        16         17         18         19         20 
 3.7762369  2.9670795 -0.8241576  2.1796402  2.5504061 

[[3]]
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13         14         15 
 1.5765136  1.7310402  0.7273943  4.0838831 -0.9946958 -2.0222258  7.5756159  3.9105252  3.9006369 -0.9939739  4.7603811  8.5079521  3.3653795  0.8546201  3.8143874 
        16         17         18         19         20 
 5.0847501 -2.6324485  2.0860695  5.7202315  9.5304238 

[[4]]
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13         14         15 
1.36751418 1.44009472 1.41155170 1.55018689 1.31378442 1.09746739 0.09224919 0.66425731 0.61047787 1.63552109 1.56096710 1.59775494 1.69658733 1.08939868 1.96183397 
        16         17         18         19         20 
1.20476936 0.94640977 0.73820689 0.65899943 1.54647028
```

Now you can directly call `lapply` like this:

```
lapply(list_dec,round)
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[[1]]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 9  8  2 10 13 12  3 10  8  0 -3 12  5  3 11 -2 -1  7  5  5 

[[2]]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 1  1  1  1  3  3  1  2  1  4  0  0  1  4  4  4  3 -1  2  3 

[[3]]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 2  2  1  4 -1 -2  8  4  4 -1  5  9  3  1  4  5 -3  2  6 10 

[[4]]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 1  1  1  2  1  1  0  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  2
```